# Posting to a Facebook Page as the Page (not a person)

Tags: php, facebook, post, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook PHP SDK 3.0.1 (latest currently).
What I need to be able to do is to post as a the identity of the Page on the Page.

I tried replacing the access_token with the access_token I get from the page (/me/accounts) however it now says token is invalid for some reason.
Facebook "impersonation" pages are offline now, and I don't see any info in the API regarding doing what I want.. maybe I'm lost or maybe not looking in the right direction..

Here's the example.php that I modified and use to archive this:

```
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'   => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

//Lists all the applications and pages
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

$page_selected = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$page_access_token = $accounts_list['data']['0']['access_token'];
echo 'page_access_token:' . $page_access_token;


<?php

if (isset($_GET['publish'])){
            try {
                $publishStream = $facebook->api("/$page_selected/feed", 'post', array(
                    'access_token'  => '$page_access_token',
                    'message'   => 'Development Test message',
                    'link'      => 'http://xxxxxxx.com',
                    'picture'   => 'http://xxxxxx/xxxx_logo.gif',
                    'name'      => 'xxxxxxxx Goes Here',
                    'description'=> 'And the exciting description here!'
                    )
                );
                //as $_GET['publish'] is set so remove it by redirecting user to the base url
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                echo($e);
                echo $publishStream;
                echo 'catch goes here';
            }
        }

?>
```

Since I can't answer my own question I edited the question.

---

Went through the whole API..

## Solution:

Before posting as the page you need to set your access_token to the one page owns.

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($page_access_token);
```

does just that, and afterwards everything goes as it normally would be expected, no need to modify post function and add "access_token" option to post.

Comment: way too much code for me to read

Comment: sorry, trimmed the code.

Comment: Facebook answers your question: [How-To: Publish updates to people who like your Open Graph Page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465)

Comment: running the example gave http 400 errors.
i don't see how making "id" your OG url would solve the issue either.
it also says nothing about how to do it using Facebook PHP SDK

Comment: This tutorial should help. It shows how to list the pages in an account: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/wrangling-with-the-facebook-graph-api/comment-page-1/#comment-390691

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on a Facebook wall as Page, not as user](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5326537/post-on-a-facebook-wall-as-page-not-as-user)

Comment: Can you create a new answer and put your solution as the answer please? I came across the same problem, providing the `access_token` only lets me post as a user onto a Page, not as the Page itself. Needed to set my FB Access Token like how you did before it worked.

Answer (score 2):

1.First you have to get the page access token.

```
public function getPageToken()
{

    $page_id = "xxxxxxxxxx";

    $page_access_token = "";

$result =  $this->facebook->api("/me/accounts");
if( !empty($result['data']) )
{
   foreach($result["data"] as $page) 
   {
     if($page["id"] == $page_id)
     {
       $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
       break;
     }
   }
}
else
{
  $url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'> top.location.href='".$url."'; </script>";
}
return $page_access_token;
}
```

2.After getting the page access token just include that token in your post to wall code.

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var token = '<?php echo $page_access_token ?>';

var wallPost = {
access_token: token,
message     : 'xxxxxxxx',
link        :  'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxx/',
picture     : 'xxxxxxxx',

name        : 'xxxxx',
caption     : 'xxxxxx',
description : 'xxxxxxx',
      };

FB.api('/pageid/feed', 'post', wallPost, function(response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
} else {
}
});
</script>
```

3.Remember this code will only publish your post on Fan page's wall and users who liked the fan page will be able to see that post as the post is posted on their own feed.

Hope this will solve your problem.