# Can not post message on Users Facebook Page as User

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the opposite problem to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239482/posting-to-a-facebook-page-as-the-page-not-a-person) (and others similar problems)

User have a test Page and he is admin of this page. User have unchecked "Posting Preferences" checkbox (in Page Edit Info->Your Settings) for allowing User to post message on page as User or as Page. 
My application asks all required permissions for posting messages to Users Page (manage_pages, offline_access, publish_stream, etc) and then storing access_token to the database.

When my application tried to post message to page as Page - it works fine
But when my application tried to post message to page as User - it still post as Page - Why it happen?
I provide only user access_token and not his Page access_token
Here is a sample code

`$facebook->setAccessToken($user_access_token);`

```
$facebook->api("/$page_id/feed", 'post', array(
                'access_token'  => "$user_access_token",//not necessarily
                'message'   => 'test'
                );
```

This code works fine for other users - they can posting messages to this page as User via my application

So, what's wrong here? Maybe it is a bug in Graph API?  :)

Comment: Hm, it is very strange, but I've tried call the same method via Graph Explorer and my test message also post as Page, but I'm logged in with my facebook account and not Page account

Comment: Looks like it is a bug. Facebook has been changed the status of the my [bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/408406055876958) to Assigned  it and set Priority to High

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding [this answer](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/408406055876958/?comment_id=596187607132950) "page admins cannot currently posts to pages as themselves through the Graph API"
:(

Answer (score 0):

I think that's why they introduced the Voice feature, so sooner there will be a API compatibility on that too.