# Facebook Post Link as Page Issue

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am writing a simple Facebook page tab app that will allow me to post messages (status updates, links, photos and videos) to multiple pages.

I am having an issue with the Facebook API (using the PHP SDK) trying to post various things to a page's timeline.

When I post a status update, it successfully posts under the name of the page.

```
    $pages = $this->facebook->api('me/accounts', 'GET');
    $pages = json_decode(json_encode($pages), FALSE);

    foreach ($pages->data as $page) {
        if (in_array($page->id, $_POST['pages'])) {

            $data = array(
                'access_token' => $page->access_token,
                'message' => Arr::get('status', $_POST)
            );

            $queryString = http_build_query($data);

            $this->facebook->api("$page->id/feed?".$queryString, 'POST');
        }
    }
```

As soon as I add any more parameters (i.e. attempt to post a link) the post is made under my admin account (i.e. Chris Hayes posted a link to 'Page X').

```
    $pages = $this->facebook->api('me/accounts', 'GET');
    $pages = json_decode(json_encode($pages), FALSE);

    foreach ($pages->data as $page) {
        if (in_array($page->id, $_POST['pages'])) {

            $data = array(
                'access_token' => $page->access_token,
                'link' => Arr::get('link', $_POST),
                'message' => Arr::get('status', $_POST)
            );

            $queryString = http_build_query($data);

            $this->facebook->api("$page->id/feed?".$queryString, 'POST');
        }
    }
```

I have no idea what's going on here. Literally the only thing that has changed is adding the 'link' parameter. If anyone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it!

**Edit** The permissions I've acquired are: email, user_about_me, user_likes, user_birthday, manage_pages, publish_stream

Regards,
Chris

Comment: First, write out the actual access_token used, and put it through the debug tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: It says it's an access token for my app, valid for another hour, with the following perms: create_note email manage_pages photo_upload publish_actions publish_stream share_item status_update user_about_me user_birthday user_likes video_upload. It has my user id associated with it, should it?

Comment: No, it should not - you do not want to post as user, but as page instead. So get a page access token.

Comment: Is that not a page access token I am using? In the documentation it says you can use the endpoint 'me/accounts' to get a list of all of your pages with access tokens included. Are these different page tokens than if you were to use the '/PAGE_ID?fields=access_token' endpoint?

Comment: Just to clarify when I ran the page token through the debugger it gave me the APP ID, PROFILE ID, and USER ID.

Comment: Try posting to `pageid/links` instead of `pageid/feed`, according to a comment in this bug report that helps: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/482882205102783

Comment: I found a fix, but I will try this method regardless (and read the bug report). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another post.

```
    $pages = $this->facebook->api('me/accounts', 'GET');
    $pages = json_decode(json_encode($pages), FALSE);

    foreach ($pages->data as $page) {
        if (in_array($page->id, $_POST['pages'])) {

            $this->facebook->setAccessToken($page->access_token);

            $data = array(
                'access_token' => $page->access_token,
                'name' => 'Facebook API: Posting As A Page',
                'link' => 'https://www.webniraj.com/2012/08/09/facebook-api-posting-as-a-page/',
                'caption' => 'The Facebook API lets you post to Pages you own automatically - either as real-time updates or in the case that you want to schedule posts.',
                'message' => 'Check out my new blog post!'
            );

            $queryString = http_build_query($data);

            $this->facebook->api("$page->id/feed?".$queryString, 'POST');
        }
    }
```

The key was to set the page access token via the Facebook SDK. This may be because I use the library elsewhere to set the access token as the user's; I guess the library must override the token sent in as a parameter.

```
$this->facebook->setAccessToken($page->access_token);
```

**Reference:** [Posting to a Facebook Page as the Page (not a person)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239482/posting-to-a-facebook-page-as-the-page-not-a-person)

---

**EDIT:** Another issue I just discovered is that I was building the query string myself and appending it to the API endpoint, like so:

```
$this->facebook->api("$page->id/feed?".$queryString, 'POST');
```

What you are supposed to do is send the $data array in as the third parameter of the API call:

```
$this->facebook->api("$page->id/feed", 'POST', $data);
```

The PHP SDK looks for an 'access_token' parameter in the $data, and because I wasn't sending in that array it wasn't finding it (and thus defaulted to using my user access token I had set previously).

After sending the data in as the third parameter of the API call I was able to remove the line:

```
$this->facebook->setAccessToken($page->access_token);
```